# Endless Scrolling Kendo MVC Grid for Local data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, scroll, kendo-ui, grid

I'm trying to add Endless scrolling feature to ASP.NET MVC web application.
Telerik has demo for Endless scrolling for Remote data going to webservice.  It mentions that you can use it for local data as well.
[Endless Scrolling Remote data](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/endless-scrolling-remote)

Our data is being returned via a method in controller that connects to SSAS cube.

Here is razor code on our view:

```
`@(Html.Kendo().Grid<BudgetService.EntityModels.Revenue>()
   .Name("revenuesGrid")
   .Columns(columns =>
   {
columns.Bound(o => o.Fund).ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("Fund: #= value # Total: #= count #");
columns.Bound(o => o.Unit).ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("Unit: #= value # Total: #= count #");
columns.Bound(o => o.Object).ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("Object: #= value # Total: #= count #");
columns.Bound(o => o.ObjectDescription).Filterable(false);
columns.Bound(o => o.Appr).ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("Appropation: #= value # Total: #= count #");
columns.Bound(o => o.AdoptedAmount).Filterable(false).Format("{0:C}").ClientGroupFooterTemplate("#= kendo.toString(sum,'c')#");
columns.Bound(o => o.RevisedAmount).Filterable(false).Format("{0:C}")
.ClientGroupFooterTemplate("#= kendo.toString(sum,'c')#");
columns.Bound(o => o.ActualAmount).Filterable(false).Format("{0:C}")
.ClientGroupFooterTemplate("#= kendo.toString(sum,'c')#");
columns.Bound(o => o.RevisedVariance).Filterable(false).Format("{0:C}")
.ClientGroupFooterTemplate("#= kendo.toString(sum,'c')#");
})
.Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu))
.Scrollable(sc => sc.Endless(true))
.DataSource(
dataSource => dataSource
.Ajax()
.PageSize(25)
.Read(read => read.Action("BudgetRevenues", "BudgetVsActuals"))
 ))`
```

AND controller (BudgetVsActuals.cs) method:

```
`public JsonResult BudgetRevenues([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            Logger.Debug("Starting BudgetRevenues - with request: " + request);
            var results = BIreporter.GetBudgetData(MdxFile.Revenues);
            return Json(results.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }`
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Just checked example on 2017.3.1026 version and didn't have any issues. Works perfectly. Please provide more info.